# Monetdb limit results displayed after query

Tags: sql, monetdb

I would like to know if there is any way of limiting the number of output results in monetdb, like it's done in Oracle for example, using:

```
.SET RETCANCEL ON
.SET RETLIMIT -1
```

EDIT: I have found the way of limiting the number of the output rows adding the following sql after query:

```
limit 1 offset 0;
```

But I'm not sure if it does the same thing.. It's important because I'm measuring the speed of different databases and such kind of things are quite important.

Thanks a lot,
Serhiy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `limit 1 offset 0;` does the job.

Comment: ````limit 42;```` also does the trick. (````offset```` defaults to 0.)